# If the following piecewise function is continuous

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus

If the following piecewise function is continuous, what is the value of $\alpha$

$
f(x,y)=
\begin{cases}
 arctan(\dfrac{|x|+|y|}{x^2+y^2})&\text{if}\, (x,y)\ne(0,0)\\
 \alpha&\text{if}\, (x,y)=(0,0)
\end{cases}
$

First I think I need to evaluate the limit of this function but I couldn't find the following limit

$$\lim\limits_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}arctan(\dfrac{|x|+|y|}{x^2+y^2})  $$

I checked this limit from wolfarm calculator but that says this limit does not exist.
So what can I do here ? please help

Comment: You have to distiguish the cases when finding the limit i.e $x>0$ or $x<0$

Comment: Alpha evaluates the limit in the complex, this is why it fails. Check this: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=limit+arctan%28%28%7Cre%28z%29%7C%2B%7Cim%28z%29%7C%29%2F%28re%5E2%28z%29%2Bim%5E2%28z%29%29%29

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: transform into polar coordinates, $x=r \cos \theta$ and $y = r \sin \theta$.

Comment: Why the downvote ? Is there something wrong ?

Answer (score 3):

Since $|x|+|y| \geq \sqrt {x^{2}+y^{2}}$ we see that $f(x,y) \to \arctan(\infty)= \frac{\pi} 2 $ as $(x,y) \to (0,0)$. Hence $f$ is continuous iff $\alpha =\frac {\pi} 2$

Answer (score 1):

Note that
$$\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} \dfrac{|x|+|y|}{x^2+y^2} = +\infty.$$

Then, as $\arctan$ is a continuous function,
$$\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} \arctan\left(\dfrac{|x|+|y|}{x^2+y^2}\right) = \arctan(+\infty) = \dfrac{\pi}{2}.$$

Then, $\alpha$ must be $\pi/2$.

Comment: The problem lies in proving the first limit in my opinion.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

$$\frac{|x|+|y|}{x^2+y^2}\ge\frac{|x|+|y|}{(|x|+|y|)^2}=\frac1{|x|+|y|}\to\infty.$$